# Appium Android driver is un installing for second time even full reset is false

Tags: selenium, appium, appium-android, appium-java

Appium Android driver is un installing for second time even full reset is false. Below are cases i am attaching.

** First time installing as expected **

```
capabilities.setCapability("noReset", false);
capabilities.setCapability("fullReset", true);
androidDriver = makeAndroidDriver(serverUrl, capabilities);
```

** Here also uninstalling even fullReset= true and noReset=false**

```
capabilities.setCapability("noReset", true);
capabilities.setCapability("fullReset", false);
androidDriver = makeAndroidDriver(serverUrl, capabilities);
```

** for third time and next onwards, it is not uninstalling **

```
capabilities.setCapability("noReset", true);
capabilities.setCapability("fullReset", false);
androidDriver = makeAndroidDriver(serverUrl, capabilities);
```

** When i change capabilities fullrest=true then reinstalling as expected.but again same as above scenarios **

```
capabilities.setCapability("noReset", false);
capabilities.setCapability("fullReset", true);
androidDriver = makeAndroidDriver(serverUrl, capabilities);
```

The problem here AndroidDrviver not initializing second time properlly after fullRset=false. This one is happening only in android. In IOS its is working properlly Please help. Tq in advance.

Comment: Here in makeAndroidDriver () method simple calling this..new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(server, caps);

Answer (score 0):

This will work fine . Since I am guessing that AUT(Application Under Test) is getting fresh installation and moreover appium is started with new session

** Here also uninstalling even fullReset= true and noReset=false**

For this

> fullReset=true : Reset app state by uninstalling app. This will also remove the app after the session is complete.

> noReset=false : In your case it will not matter . Since if you start again your app .It will be a fresh installation so by default noReset=true.

** for third time and next onwards, it is not uninstalling ** [Which is correct only]
For this

> fullReset:false : So App will not get removed or its gonna clear its state

> noReset:true : It will not re-install your AUT but it will reset app state before this session

** When i change capabilities fullrest=true then reinstalling as expected.but again same as above scenarios **

For this: Not able to identify your issue .

For more info on this capabilities . Please go and visit once appium java docs .
[Appium Capabilities Docs](https://developers.perfectomobile.com/display/PD/Supported+Appium+capabilities)

[Official-Appium Docs Link](https://appium.io/docs/en/about-appium/api/#appium-api-documentation)

[Reset Statergies on ANDROID & iOS](https://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/other/reset-strategies/index.html)